# How to display JSON using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to display the value based on selected value on drop down list with using Get method of Ajax from the url,

based on schema i have to add the value of selected item to the meddle of url and then i can get the relative data from the server:

this is my code:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'url',
   success: function(data) {
   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#tbl2").append("<option>"+data[i]+"</option>");
     }
   }
});

var one = 'http://gate.atlascon.cz:9999/rest/a/';
var middle = $('#tbl2 :selected').text(); // it should be the selected item from last get method
var end = '/namespace';
var url_t = one + middle + end ;


$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: url_t,
   success: function(data2) {
   $("#text-area").append(data2);
   }
```

but it is not work!

i am new in programming, could you please help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this in your ajax `success()`:

```
data.forEach(function(item) {
  $("#tbl").find('tbody')
      .append($('<tr>')
          .append($('<td>').text(item))
      );
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: 'url',
   success: function(data) {

   for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $("#tbl").append("<tr><td>"+data[i]+"</td></tr>");
     }
   }
});
```

Comment: is this answer is useful?

Comment: yes, thanks. know i have a error 405, with sending data by post method do you know how to solve it?